# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Slider'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm developing an `asp.NET` application using `Entity Framework` and I'm getting the following exception whenever I try to create a record in my `dbo.Slider` table:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException:
>   An error occurred while updating the entries.
>   See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException:
>   An error occurred while updating the entries.
>   See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.Slider'. at ...

I'm using an Entity Framework service called `efService` that I created and call on my code-behind form:

```
protected Services.EFService efService = new Services.EFService();
```

I try to create the slider on a button click and here's the section of code I use before it breaks in the button:

```
slider.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
slider.Caption = txbPhotoCaptionCreate.Text;
slider.IsPublic = cbxPhotoPublicCreate.Checked;
slider.Path = string.Empty;
slider.ThumbnailPath = string.Empty;
slider.DisplayPath = string.Empty;

int sliderId = efService.CreateSlider(slider);  // It breaks here
```

Here is the `CreateSlider efService` that I've made:

```
public int CreateSlider(Models.EF.Slider slider)
{
    DB.Sliders.Add(slider);
    DB.SaveChanges();

    return slider.Id;
}
```

This all works on my other tables which have pretty much the exact same functionality.

Here's the SQL I use to create my `Slider` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Slider] 
(
    [Id]              INT IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [Caption]         VARCHAR (50)       NOT NULL,
    [Position]        INT                NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    [IsPublic]        BIT                NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    [Path]            NVARCHAR (250)     NULL,
    [ThumbnailPath]   NVARCHAR (250)     NULL,
    [DisplayPath]     NVARCHAR (250)     NULL,
    [DateCreated]     DATETIME           NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

There are no build errors, the whole application runs fine except when I try to create a record for `Slider`. Through a lot of debugging I can conclude that the problem occurs when the `DB.SaveChanges()` occurs.

Comment: Are you sure that EF is pointing to the Same database as the one you executed that SQL query on ? Debug that method and check the `DB` object, it has a `Database` property which should hold the `ConnectionString`.

Comment: Yes, exactly like it does to my other tables

Comment: @user3185569 that put me on the right track.  I had created the DB locally but the application was using a cloud DB.  So the problem was actually in the web-config with me point to the wrong DB.  You can answer it if you want.

Comment: Answered just now..

Comment: Thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, you need to make sure that the `context` in pointing to the same database as the one which you created the table in.

You can do that by debuging the method `CreateSlider` and checking the `DB` object, it has a `Database` property which should hold the excepted `ConnectionString`.